# How to stop multiple songs playing at same time?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a list of songs i put manually inside my app and it currently have 3 functions: start, pause and stop (using ImageViews).

The problem is that i can play multiple songs at the same time that is **not** supposed to be like that. I really cant find the issue here and hope someone can help.

[This is a demonstration on my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXjSn.png)

I want it to STOP currently playing song when another song is being clicked on.

Here is my code for my play button:

```
viewholder.playB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (currentSong == null || song != currentSong) {
                currentSong = song;

                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, song.getSong());
            }
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                viewholder.playB.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_black);
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                viewholder.playB.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_black);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: don't create `MediaPlayer` in a viewHolder, but use ONE single instance.

Comment: But then it will only play my first song in the list no matter which song i pick.

Comment: if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }else
            mediaPlayer.start();

Answer (score 1):

Instead of always creating a new instance of `MediaPlayer` every time the event `onClick` is called, you should **create a single instance and reused it**.

---

To play a new song don't forget to reset your player first. Here is an example:

```
mPlayer.reset();
mPlayer.setDataSource(context, song.getSong());
```

Comment: I tried the following what you suggest but i got an error:

**Wrong 2nd argument of type 'int'. required: 'Uri'**

Comment: @Delice if your `song.getSong()` returns a path you should use the `setDataSource` without the context.

Comment: song.getSong() returns an arraylist of songs. i have a java class called Song where i have my properties.

Comment: @Delice you can only play one song at a time, so you can only pass a single song.

Comment: I still dont understand the logic behind this.. I create a single instance of the mediaplayer to get the position of the song i clicked on and play it and when i clicked on another song then it has to reset the mediaplayer, right? If yes - how to properly implement this, i dont get it. Sorry for my noobish comment but im a student and still in the learning process.

Comment: @Delice just take for example a CD player... what you do what wanting to play the next one disc? possibly you would want to press stop, then eject, then replace the disc and then hit play ...while you might be trying to insert a second disc.

Comment: I tried many different things till now i and i cant simply make it work. can someone post a working code sample so i can debug to see what was the exact solution? Thank you.